# MVC Areas Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an MVC Application as follows:

```
Application
 Controllers
      HomeController
           ActionResult Index();
 Areas
      IT
           Controllers
                ITHomeController
                     ActionResult Index();
```

I have setup the links to work correctly between the main application and the IT Area.

In the URL the link to the IT area shows up as http://localhost/IT/ITHome. 
The code for the link is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("IT Page","Index","ITHome", new { area = "IT" }, null)
```

How would I have the url simply be http://localhost/IT  I'm sure it's simple.

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to change the registered route mapping e.g. add a new route that has `ITHOME` as the default controller if the area matches `IT`. Can you show your RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: You should call the controller `Home` not `ITHome`

Comment: @jumpingcode  What's the reason it should be home?  The idea in changing it was so that when I have multiple tabs open I know which home controller I'd be clicking on.

Comment: You've defined an area `IT` which means all routes will start with `/it/`. Then defined a controller named `ITHome` which by default will make the route `/it/ithome/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Look for /Areas/IT/ITAreasRegistration.cs
2. Add a route mapping in its `public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)` method, preferably at the very top or at least before the default route for the area.

Something like:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "default_IT",
                "IT",
                new { action = "Index", controller = "ITHome" },
                new[] { "YourAppNamespaceHere.Areas.IT.Controllers" }
            );
```

3. As for the link... I'd just hand code it to `<a href="/IT">IT Home</a>` and be done with it unless you are hosting this as a sub application from the wwwroot, you should be fine.

In this way you can keep your area routes separate from your normal routes.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the `ITHomeController` to `HomeController` may give you ambiguous matching.

You could change the registered route mapping e.g. add a new route that has `ITHOME` as the default controller if the area matches `IT`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "ITHome",
       "IT/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new { area = "IT", controller = "ITHome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then, just for the `IT` area, it will allow the default controller to be your `ITHomeController`.